# Question About Nullspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If the nullspace of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is defined as the space that contains all vectors $\vec{x}$ such that $$A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$$
wouldn't any vector living in some $\mathbb{R}^i$ where $i>n$ which does not have any $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ components be in the nullspace?
So for example If we have an $m\times2$ matrix, is the nullspace the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ perpendicular to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane at the origin, or the plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with only $x_3$ and $x_4$ components, or etc.

Essentially what I'm asking is: **Is the nullspace of an $m\times n$ matrix confined to $\mathbb{R}^n$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it helps to think of $m\times n$ matrices as linear operators $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. The null space of a matrix is essentially the kernel of the corresponding linear operator. It should be clear that the kernel of any mapping is a subset of the domain of that mapping so in this particular case the null space of the matrix $A$ has to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Moreover, since the operator corresponding to any matrix is linear, the nullspace of a $m\times n$ matrix is not only a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but also a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 3):

An $m\times n$ matrix $A$ can only act on vectors $\vec x\in\mathbb R^n$. It takes as an input a vector of length $n$ and gives as an output a vector of length $m$, namely $A\vec x$.

For $\vec y\in\mathbb R^i$ with $i\neq n$, the expression $A\vec y$ is ill-defined. (How would you even define it?)

Thus, yes, the nullspace is confined to $\mathbb R^n$, which is a subset of the domain of the linear operator $A$.